# node express - verify user deleting entry is the person who created it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am very new to coding in general a network person for 20 years+ but giving this a go as something to learn so please be gentle :-). This is my first time asking for help.

I am creating a node js with express back end and I am using VUE 3 for the front end.  I have user authentication setup and working as I want.

I am now trying to add a simple post feature.  Users can create posts and view other users posts.  An admin user can delete all posts but a normal user can't delete their own posts with the checks I am trying to put in place.

Post Controller

```
function _delete(req, res, next) {
    postService.getPost(req.params.id)
        .then(...post)
        .catch(next);
    
        if (Number(post)(post.accountId) !== req.user.id && req.user.role !== Role.Admin) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }
    

    postService.delete(req.params.id)
        .then(() => res.json({ message: 'Post deleted successfully' }))
        .catch(next);
```

Post Services

```
async function _delete(id) {
    const post = await getPost(id);
    await post.destroy();
}

async function getPost(id) {
    const post = await db.Post.findByPk(id);
    if (!post) throw 'Post not found';
    return post;
}
```

The bit I am struggling with is trying to get the return "post" from the getPost function and use that in the if statement in the delete function.

Would be grateful for some assistance.

Many Thanks

Steve

Comment: What is `.then(...post)` supposed to do? You need a function like `.then(post => { ... })` and in the place of the ellipses you put something like `if (Number(post.accountId) !== req.user.id ...)`

Comment: Chris Thanks very much that worked, I have spent days trying to get this working.

Comment: That's how async code works; an async function returns a Promise, and you call `.then()` on it passing another function. When the Promise resolves, it calls that function, passing the resolved result as first param. Note that if you make your `_delete` function async, you can do `const post = await postService.getPost(req.params.id);` instead. Catching the error needs a try catch block in that case though.

Comment: Thanks Chris I just had to reread you post 10 times for it to sink in.  I have swapped the code to this and it still works.  I am not sure of the benefits of this than using the then statements?

async function _delete(req, res, next) {
    const post = await postService.getPost(req.params.id)
        if (Number(post.accountId) !== req.user.id && req.user.role !== Role.Admin) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
        }

This makes a lot more sense to me and easier to read that what I had before.